# About the Hebrew word Immanuel

Tags: hebrew, isaiah

I looked in Isaiah 7:14 the Hebrew for Immanuel: 8034 [e]

```
6005 [e]
```

’êl.
אֵֽל׃
Immanuel
Noun 
The only part is translated:  ’êl!
What does ·עִמָּ֥נוּ mean?
I haven't had Hebrew in 30 years, but I want to know how it is translated?

Comment: If Susan has answered your question correctly, please select her answer as the best answer by clicking on the green check mark to the left of her answer.

Comment: related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/53637/what-is-the-meaning-and-significance-of-the-name-immanuel-isaiah-714

Answer (score 5):

It means "with us". The preposition [עִם](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/767/mode/1up) (*ʿim*), meaning "with", is followed by the first person plural pronominal suffix נוּ- (*-nû*), meaning "us". (See [GKC §103](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius'_Hebrew_Grammar/103._Prepositions_with_Pronominal_Suffixes_and_in_the_Plural_Form).) For the same phrase, see Isaiah 8:10b:

> ‏דַּבְּרוּ דָבָר וְלֹא יָקוּם כִּ֥י **עִמָּ֖נוּ אֵל**
>   Speak a word, but it will not stand,
>           for **God is with us**. (ESV)

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 1:23 actually gives you the interpretation without any use of a dictionary or commentary.  And the beautiful thing about this commentary is it comes from the holy scriptures themselves.  Which is one of the first rules for Bible study, to let scripture interpret scripture.  In addition, you will find this referring to Jesus as the fulfillment of this name.  He is not a third person in the Godhead, but very God manifest in the flesh, the messiah!1timothy 3:16,2Cor. 5:19.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you have not already taken the Tour, you may find that helpful for getting going in Hermeneutics. When a question expressly asks for a Hebrew word used in the Bible to have its meaning clarified, answers need to state translation information. If you are unable to do that, then the comments section would be best for points such as you make. But do click the blue Tour link below to get such information.